# Update entry with file instance DRF, Vue.js 3

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I have a table that has a `models.FileField` in it. I'm able to create the file from a Vue.js website `POST` request, but when I want to update the instance I have to upload the file again.

The problem is not from Vue.js, because I can't update even using the DRF pre-built page.
[image]

How can I update the instance without having to upload the document again?

Comment: Use `PATCH`. It allows you to update fields that you want to update for your model instance. You don't need to provide all fields in your data payload.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot.